# Manipulate AJAX function on success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "url.com",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data){


          $(data). //how?

        }
    });
```

THe data object returns a HTML page, and i just want to get a specific DIV from the data object. I've tried $(data).find('id/class') but it returns just a string. I tried $("div", data); it returns all divs but not the specific one i want with some id. Im out of ideas, anyone can help?

Comment: try `var $result = $(data).filter('div#result');`

Comment: It seem very odd that `$("div", data);` would give results but `$(data).find('id/class')` would give you a string. `find()` shouldn't be able to return a string.

Comment: @ozil I want the content of the div..

Comment: @Quentin Im doing a website for IE8, maybe because of that :D

Comment: @NeoChrome — Does the problem only occur in IE8? Have you tested in any other browsers?

Comment: @ozil Yes i did, but var $result = $(data).filter('div#result'); is the answer it seems!

Comment: @NeoChrome — You said that returned a string before

Comment: @Neo Chrome `data = "<div id='data'>1</div><div id='data1'>2</div><div id='data2'>3</div>";` suppose `data1` is desired `id`. what is you desired result.

Comment: @ozil i have <table> in div and it has 5 <tr>, and on refresh i want to repopulate the <tr>, but it seems it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In success response of your data you have to parse your `HTML` and apply filter on that.

```
var result =  $($.parseHTML(data)).filter("div#your_id");
```